# Combine values in 4 columns to a single unique value

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to combine values of every row in 4 columns to get single unique value and make a new column of these values in R. For eg I have a dataframe as below:

```
 Col_1   Col_2  Col_3  Col_4
  1      23       45    12 
  0      45       17    4
  0     667       60    5
  64     123      299   5
  87      23      60    6
```

Now the new column col_5 that I want, should contain a unique value in all its rows which represent these 4 values... **for eg the first row is (1,23,45,12) which is a unique combination in my dataframe but individual values in the columns are not, hence I want to assign this combination a unique value in col_5 for all the rows.** Please suggest a function in R.

Also if at all, the combination occurs more than once,  the value in col_5 for such repetition should be the same.

I have tried using `DT[, lapply(.SD,sum), by=list(col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4)]` and
`DT[, Mean:=mean(col_4), by=list(col_1,col_2,col_3)]` but it does not give me unique values.

Comment: Do you want the value for column 5 to be numeric? and if yes, it should have some specific property based on the values of Col_1, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I want the value to be numeric and the value should be some function of values in the 4 columns.

Comment: You can use `df$Col_5 <- do.call(paste, df)` which would give a result for the first row as `1 23 45 12`. I doubt that it would be possible to get the desired result you describe (separated by commas) as a column of class `numeric` because such entries are not normal numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
df$Col_5 <- paste(df$Col_1,df$Col_2,df$Col_3,df$Col_4,sep=",")
```

you get the desired result. An alternative for this (inspired by @beginneR) is:

```
df$Col_5 <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep=","))
```

As already noted by @beginneR, this can't be a numeric variable:

```
> class(df[,5])
[1] "character"
```

---

When you want a numeric value, you can also do that with:

```
df$Col_5 <- paste0(sprintf("%03s",df$Col_1),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_2),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_3),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_4))
```

and when you want it to be numeric:

```
df$Col_5 <- as.numeric(paste0(sprintf("%03s",df$Col_1),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_2),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_3),sprintf("%03s",df$Col_4)))
```

Comment: +1 nice, I was wondering how to include the `sep=","` in the `do.call`. Now I know

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a way to get a numerical value... I so needed it for further processing of my data...!

Comment: @ShreedharPawar you're welcome, did you see my other comment?

Comment: Yup I saw it and also thanked u for giving a piece of advice, but can't see my comment now. But I will surely remember to vote up for the answers I get and I had also voted u up for the answer priorly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a numeric value by using `interaction()`. This will create a factor which you can then convert to numeric

```
dd$Col_5 <- as.numeric(interaction(dd[1:4], drop=T))
```

The number itself will be arbitrary, but it will be unique for every combination.

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I know to get a numerical value too.

Comment: Will this give a same value for a combination if the combination is repeated...?

Comment: As long as you do in all the the same data.set, then yes, duplicates will get the same value.

Answer (score 2):

If `dd` is the dataset:

```
library(qdap)
transform(dd, Col_5=paste2(dd,sep=","))
```

or

```
colpaste2df(dd, list(Col_5=1:4),sep=",")
     Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_4     Col_5
1     1    23    45    12   1,23,45,12
2     0    45    17     4    0,45,17,4
3     0   667    60     5   0,667,60,5
4    64   123   299     5 64,123,299,5
5    87    23    60     6   87,23,60,6
```

Answer (score 0):

From **dplyr**, use [`group_indices`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_indices.html):

```
group_indices(mtcars, gear, carb)
```

This is like `interaction()` in that you don't have to worry about two strings being the same with `paste()`, but no need for factors.