# Group Data in R for consecutive rows

Tags: r

If there's not a quick 1-3 liner for this in R, I'll definitely just use linux `sort` and a short python program using `groupby`, so don't bend over backwards trying to get something crazy working. Here's the input data frame:

```
df_in <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  weight = c(150,150,151,150,150,170,170,170,171,171),
  start_day = c(1,4,7,10,11,5,10,15,20,25),
  end_day = c(4,7,10,11,30,10,15,20,25,30)
)
   ID weight start_day end_day
1   1    150         1       4
2   1    150         4       7
3   1    151         7      10
4   1    150        10      11
5   1    150        11      30
6   2    170         5      10
7   2    170        10      15
8   2    170        15      20
9   2    171        20      25
10  2    171        25      30
```

I would like to do some basic aggregation by `ID` and `weight`, but only when the group is in consecutive rows of `df_in`. Specifically, the desired output is

```
df_desired_out <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2),
  weight = c(150,151,150,170,171),
  min_day = c(1,7,10,5,20),
  max_day = c(7,10,30,20,30)
)
  ID weight min_day max_day
1  1    150       1       7
2  1    151       7      10
3  1    150      10      30
4  2    170       5      20
5  2    171      20      30
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629894/how-to-solve-gaps-and-island-problems-in-r-and-performance-vs-sql) seems to be extremely close to what I want, but I'm having lots of trouble adapting it for some reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In *dplyr*, I would do this by creating another grouping variable for the consecutive rows.  This is what the code `cumsum(c(1, diff(weight) != 0)` is doing in the code chunk below.  An example of this is also [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/237).

The group creation can be done within `group_by`, and then you can proceed accordingly with making any summaries by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df_in %>%
    group_by(ID, group_weight = cumsum(c(1, diff(weight) != 0)), weight) %>%
    summarise(start_day = min(start_day), end_day = max(end_day))

Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
Groups: ID, group_weight [?]

     ID group_weight weight start_day end_day
  (dbl)        (dbl)  (dbl)     (dbl)   (dbl)
1     1            1    150         1       7
2     1            2    151         7      10
3     1            3    150        10      30
4     2            4    170         5      20
5     2            5    171        20      30
```

This approach does leave you with the extra grouping variable in the dataset, which can be removed, if needed, with `select(-group_weight)` after ungrouping.

Answer (score 1):

First we combine `ID` and `weight`. The quick-and-dirty way is using paste:

```
df_in$id_weight <- paste(df_in$id, df_in$weight, sep='_')
df_in
   ID weight start_day end_day id_weight
1   1    150         1       4     1_150
2   1    150         4       7     1_150
3   1    151         7      10     1_151
4   1    150        10      11     1_150
5   1    150        11      30     1_150
6   2    170         5      10     2_170
7   2    170        10      15     2_170
8   2    170        15      20     2_170
9   2    171        20      25     2_171
10  2    171        25      30     2_171
```

Safer way is to use `interaction` or `group_indices`: [Combine values in 4 columns to a single unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24355480/3163618)

We can group consecutively using `rle`.

```
rlel <- rle(df_in$id_weight)$lengths
df_in$group <- unlist(lapply(1:length(rlel), function(i) rep(i, rlel[i])))
df_in
   ID weight start_day end_day id_weight group
1   1    150         1       4     1_150     1
2   1    150         4       7     1_150     1
3   1    151         7      10     1_151     2
4   1    150        10      11     1_150     3
5   1    150        11      30     1_150     3
6   2    170         5      10     2_170     4
7   2    170        10      15     2_170     4
8   2    170        15      20     2_170     4
9   2    171        20      25     2_171     5
10  2    171        25      30     2_171     5
```

Now with the convenient group number we can summarize by group.

```
df_in %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(id_weight = id_weight[1], 
            start_day = min(start_day), 
            end_day = max(end_day))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  group id_weight start_day end_day
  <int> <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 1_150             1       7
2     2 1_151             7      10
3     3 1_150            10      30
4     4 2_170             5      20
5     5 2_171            20      30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with(df_in, {
  aggregate(day, list('ID'=ID, 'weight'=weight), 
            function(x) c('min_day' = min(x), 'max_day' = max(x)))
})
```

Produces:

```
  ID weight x.min_day x.max_day
1  1    150         1         5
2  1    151         3         3
3  2    170         1         3
4  2    171         4         5
```

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this produces the same output as the incorrect data.table solution included in the quesiton. I was hoping to have it only group rows that were consecutive in the original data frame. The desired output is in the question and has 3 rows for `ID=1`.

Comment: @user673173 I think you should edit your problem description much more clearly. I'm not confident that aosmith's solution of using the `cumsum(c(1, diff(weight) != 0)` would get what you want in general, despite that it seems to work in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that in Base R is defining an special index column as follow:

```
df_in$index <- cumsum(ifelse(c(0,diff(df_in$weight)),1,0))
aggregate(df_in, cbind(start_day, end_day) ~ weight+index, function(x) c(min=min(x), max=max(x)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  weight index start_day.min start_day.max end_day.min end_day.max
1    150     0             1             4           4           7
2    151     1             7             7          10          10
3    150     2            10            11          11          30
4    170     3             5            15          10          20
5    171     4            20            25          25          30
```