# Perform a cumulative group operations with R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to process data based on a sequential group id. There are J groups and I want to run the data processing function for groups `i < j=1..J`

The most trivial case is when each row is it's own group and you calculate the cumulative sum. However I have multiple rows in each group and the processing is more complicated than summation.

Here is an minimal example of my data format:

```
row | group | value
----|-------|------
  1 |     1 |  2065
  2 |     1 |  2075
  3 |     2 | 18008
  4 |     2 | 17655
  : |     : |     :
N-1 |   J-1 |  2345
  N |     J |  5432
```

One solution I've thought of is to replicate my data, stacking it and reassigning the groups in each data so that group `i<j` to j. This would result in a very long data frame like such:

```
row | group | value
----|-------|------
  1 |     1 |  2065
  2 |     1 |  2075
  3 |     2 |  2065
  4 |     2 |  2075
  5 |     2 | 18008
  6 |     2 | 17655
  : |     : |     :
```

However this seems tedious and inefficient as my data will be copied many times.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way of processing the data in a cumulative group by way?

Comment: Your question is unclear, not least because you end a sentence like "so that group $i"

Comment: Thanks frank, it seems math doesn't render anymore… Let me fix that

Comment: could this be of interest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529854/group-data-in-r-for-consecutive-rows

Comment: Oh yeah, tex math has never been available on this site, even though it is elsewhere on the stackexchange network. Kind of a pain to work around, so folks usually just write math in code blocks.

Comment: This can be done in a single line with SQL;  `library(sqldf); sqldf("select a.[group], b.value from (select distinct [group] from DF) a join DF b on a.[group] >= b.[group]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One methodology that should work here is to split the data.frame by group id, and then run a `for` loop (or `lapply`) with the the cumulative groups. Below is an example using a `for` loop as I think it is will be more straightforward to implement.

```
# split data.frame by group ID
myList <- split(df, df$group)
# initialize empty output list
myOutputList <- list()

# loop through group IDs, including the next one
for(i in seq_along(unique(df$group))) {
  # create temporary df for analysis
  myTempDf <- do.call(rbind, myList[seq_len(i)])

  ## perform analysis on myTempDf here ##

  # save results
  myOutputList[[i]] <- list(<list of analysis ouput>)
}
```

The output would be a nested list. I'd recommend naming each item in the nested list to make it easier to access, like `myOutputList[[i]][["regression.1"]]`.

Note that this assumes that the groups are properly sorted properly in the original data.frame and that the group ids are the counting numbers 1,2,3,4,... as in your example.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with (basically) but I was hoping there was a cleaner way.

Comment: There are other approaches, like building a second list of data.frames using `Reduce` with accumulate=TRUE that hold each of your desired analysis data.frames and then looping through that for the analysis, but it just moves the analysis around in my opinion (and takes up more memory) rather than making it cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Here are three example, one with `aggregate`, one with `data.table` and the last one with `dplyr` as you asked.

First create the dataframe

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

group <- c(1,1,2,2,3)
value <- c(2065, 2075, 18008, 17655, 561)
```

With **data.table** you can use this function

```
dat <- data.table(group, value)
recap <- dat[, list(somma = sum(value)), by = group]
```

With **aggregate** from the package stats

```
dat <- data.frame(group, value)
aggregate(dat$value, by=list(Group=dat$group), FUN=sum)
```

Then with **dplyr**

```
dat %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(result = sum(value))
```

These will give you

```
group | result
---------------
  1   |  4140
  2   |  35663
  3   |  561
```

Comment: This is just a plain old group by operation. In this example I would expect results 4140, 39803, 40364. In your example this could be done by taking the cumulative sum of the group by operation -- but this strategy does not work in other cases (performing more complicated processing).

Comment: So you want the cumulative sum by group and then show the results cumulated within the other groups?
Because the cumulated sum by group is  4140, 35663 and 561 right?

Comment: The function is arbitrary but the processing should be cumulative. That is to say first perform the function on data for group 1, then groups 1 and 2, then groups 1, 2, and 3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are several approaches:

**1) sqldf** This is being transferred from the comments.  I had originally put it there since it is not a dplyr solution but it seems you are considering others.  We join the unique group values with the data frame on the indicated condition. A single SQL statement will do it:

```
DF <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 2, 2), value = 1:4) # test data

library(sqldf)
outDF <- sqldf("select a.[group], b.value 
                from 
                     (select distinct [group] from DF) a 
                     join DF b on a.[group] >= b.[group]")
```

giving:

```
> outDF
  group value
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     2     4
```

and now we can process over the groups.  Depending on what `fun` looks like one of these might do it:

```
aggregate(value ~ group, outDF, fun)

tapply(outDF$value, outDF$group, fun)

by(outDF, outDF$group, fun)

ave(outDF$value, outDF$group, FUN = fun)
```

If the operation were sum, say, rather than a separate aggregation it could be combined with the above like this.

```
sqldf("select a.[group], sum(b.value) cumsum
       from (select distinct [group] from DF) a join DF b on a.[group] >= b.[group] 
       group by a.[group]")
```

giving:

```
  group cumsum
1     1      3
2     2     10
```

Note that

- `group` is an SQL keyword which is why we escaped it using `[group]`
- we have assumed that it is desired to accumulate groups that are numerically equal or less than the current group which is the case in the example in the question.  If a different order were desired we could create another grouping variable whose ordering reflected that desired.

**2) base**  This does not use any packages.  We have assumed that it is desired to accumulate the current group and groups that appear prior to it in the split so that groups are accumulated in numerical order; however, if we want a different order we could make `group` into a factor and order the levels as desired since `split` output will be in the order of the grouping factor's levels.

```
L <- Reduce(rbind, split(DF, DF$group), acc = TRUE)
do.call("rbind", lapply(L, transform, group = tail(group, 1)))
```

giving:

```
  group value
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     2     4
```

**3) magrittr** (2) can be rewritten using magrittr like this:

```
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  Reduce(f = rbind, acc = TRUE) %>%
  lapply(transform, group = tail(group, 1)) %>%
  do.call(what = "rbind")
```

giving the same result as in (2).